# Python Selenium: find element for favorite/unfavorite button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, favorite

I'm trying to find all elements on a page that have not already been clicked, or 'favorited.'

Here is the html for an element that is favorited:

```
<a class="button-fave unfavorited-button favorited-button" rel="78853399" alt="Add to favorites">
    <div class="button-spinner"></div>
    <span class="status-text">Favorite</span>
</a>
```

Here is the html code for when the element is not favorited:

```
<a class="button-fave unfavorited-button" rel="78853399" alt="Add to favorites">
    <div class="button-spinner"></div>
    <span class="status-text">Favorite</span>
</a>
```

I have tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-fave unfavorited-button')
```

but I get the following:

> The given selector button-fave unfavorited-button is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted

The following works, but it doesn't discern between favorited elements and unfavorited elements:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('button-fave')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all `a` elements [not having](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) `favorited-button` class:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a:not(.favorited-button)")
```